# get form submit value in pop up using jquery is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have used open model content using Ajax page and now I want that pop-up form data while submitting that pop-up. I am not able to get that data to submit function.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQdkI.png)

on Edit button i have open pop-up using ajax page and in that pop-up i have show one form so i want that pop up data on submit

using this code

```
function edit_pd(){ 
alert("submit"); 
var pid = $('#pid').val(); 
var pname = $('#pname').val(); 
var phone = $('#phone').val(); 
var date = $('#datepicker11').val(); 
var email = $('#email').val(); 
var add = $('#address').val(); 
var ref = $('#ref').val(); 

    alert("data"+pid+" name "+pname+" phone "+phone+" date "+date+" email "+email+" add "+add+" ref "+ref); 
    var datastring = $("#preview_form").serialize(); 
    alert("dd data "+datastring); 
    }
```

i can get value but not all form value

Comment: show us the code please?

Comment: Show us what you have so far and point to problematic part.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: using this code function edit_pd(){
  alert("submit");
  var pid = $('#pid').val();
  var pname = $('#pname').val();
  var phone = $('#phone').val();
  var date = $('#datepicker11').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var add = $('#address').val();
  var ref = $('#ref').val();
  alert("data"+pid+" name "+pname+" phone "+phone+" date "+date+" email "+email+" add "+add+" ref "+ref);
  var datastring = $("#preview_form").serialize();
  alert("ddddata "+datastring);
  } i can get value but not all form value

Comment: @sunitamehta please use the Edit feature to add the code to your question and format it so that it's readable. Code in comments is hard to read and comprehend quickly - would you like to try and parse what you've just pasted in there if you've never seen it before??